# What does binding mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, binding

I'm reading this great book called Eloquent JavaScript but I'm confused by the use of the word "binding" in [this example:](https://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html)

> It is possible to include symbol properties in object expressions and
>   classes by using square brackets around the property name. That causes
>   the property name to be evaluated, much like the square bracket
>   property access notation, which allows us to refer to a binding that
>   holds the symbol.

```
let stringObject = {
  [toStringSymbol]() { return "a jute rope"; }
};
console.log(stringObject[toStringSymbol]());
// → a jute rope
```

As I understand it (so far in my JS journey), "binding" relates to specifying which `this` or object context in which a function operates. [See here.](https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/2a4ac91f9f42ec0ef9cd0d18e4e71262). Binding is perhaps something related to context. That is why we have `.bind()`.

But in this example we are binding something else (a method whose key is a symbol). Does `binding` just mean attaching a property (primitive or method) to an object?

Comment: See also [Is a variable declaration the same as a variable's binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50898687/1048572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *binding* in JavaScript is the formal terminology for what a lot of people refer to as a *variable*. In ES2015+, a variable can be defined with the `let` keyword, but you can also define constant with the `const` keyword. A *binding* could refer to either a variable or a constant.

Reference: See chapter 2, page 1 of Eloquent JavaScript, under the section heading 'Bindings' (https://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html)

Answer (score 11):

*Does binding just mean attaching a property (primitive or method) to an object?*

**No**

Your previous paragraph provides a better explanation:

*"binding" relates to specifying which this or object context*

**Sort of**

Everything tracked by JavaScript is bound. In fact, the definition of `undefined` means JavaScript cannot find a bound identifier.

**Answer**

Binding something in JavaScript means recording that identifier in a specific `Environment Record`. Each `Environment Record` is related to a specific `Execution Context` - and that binds the identifier (variable or function name) to the `this` keyword for that execution context.

**Reference**

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5

**Less Formally**

Think of Environment Records as buckets of stuff. These are not Objects or Functions or Variables or anything we *code* in JavaScript, these buckets contain all these things. There are many buckets in a JavaScript application. Each bucket operates independently from the other buckets. That independence is represented as a Context (or Execution Context) in JavaScript. But sometimes we want to use stuff from one bucket inside a different bucket. That is where binding comes in. We can bind stuff from one bucket into the context of a different bucket for execution there. (A side effect of doing all that is the `this` keyword reflects the bucket borrowing the stuff).

Comment: This is great info, thanks. It's unfortunate that Eloquent Javascript made this change when it went from 2nd to 3rd edition. It was such a great teaching tool when it referred to variables as _variables, like every other resource_. What a confusing and unnecessary change for a book targeting unexperienced developers. This info could have easily been included in a chapter explaining `.bind()` and `this` etc.

Comment: @reustin Agreed. I ended up here from the same resource and the same reason, having previously learnt ES5 a while ago, and the universal references to bindings gave me the impression that variables had been renamed in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

In context of functions, "binding can refer to setting the context (value of this) for the function."

```
function hi() {
    console.log("${this.name}");
}

const val = { name: 'Ishant' };

const bindingValue = hi.bind(val);

bindingValue(); // this will give me : "Hi! Ishant"
```

Answer (score -2):

In this book, they use binding or variable interchangeably. So simply means, a binding is a variable. I guess you started reading a book by skipping the pages, don't do it again. I will write a very simple program to illustrate.

```js
let count = 1;//count is a binding(a variable)
++count;//it's called side effect(because the original value of count binding was modified)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).